# Displaying a graph for parsed sentences with Stanford-parser

Tags: android, parsing, android-jetpack-compose, stanford-nlp, dependency-tree

I am using Android Studio and I want to know if there is any way to create a dependency tree similar to the one below as an output for parsed sentences using the stanford-parser implementation or any additional software.
[image: PARSED-SENTENCE]

I have tried implementations like chaoticity-dependensee (but it seems deprecated and does not work) and graphViz(however its output does not resemble what I am looking for and I don't know if it's possible to configure it to change its appearence. I would appreciate any information on the topic, as it is very difficult to find this subject online.